# Как внести изменения в 50 БД MySQL с данными плагина ACF?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, acf

Всем привет,

**Что имеется**

Есть сайт на Вордпрессе, который продублирован на 50 поддоменов и соответственно у каждого поддомена своя БД. На сайте установлен плагин ACF. В итоге получается 50 одинаковых сайтов по коду, но с разными БД, так как пользователи сайтов добавляют свой контент через ACF поля.

**Что требуется**

Требуется внести изменения в уже созданные через админку ACF поля на всех сайтах.

**Что попытался сделать**

Я взял одну из копий сайта, поднял на локалке и внес соответствующие изменения. Встал вопрос как продублировать эти изменения на остальные сайты. Я экспортировал БД до изменений, залил в гит, потом экспортировал БД после и перезалил в гит, чтобы увидеть какие строчки изменились. Думал решу задачу путем простых sql запросов во все БД, но это не помогло, оказалось там много чего поменялось (в основном цифры) и кажется половина из этого не относится к моим изменениям полей ACF. В SQL запросах и БД я не силен.

**Вопрос**

Подскажите, как продублировать изменения полей ACF на другие такие же сайты?

Заранее, спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поля надо создавать [через РНР код](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/) в ACF при помощи функции `acf_add_local_field_group()` (сгенерить код для вставки можно прямо из настроек ACF), а не через GUI (админку), тогда их можно обновлять добавлять через GIT/

Или поля можно обновлять [через JSON](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/local-json/), но там посложнее.

А GUI в итоге проще отключить через фильтр:

```
add_filter( 'acf/settings/show_admin', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Спасибо, похоже это действительно наиболее оптимальный вариант решения моей проблемы, только есть нюанс: я так понимаю отключение GUI через фильтр не является деактивацией всех полей, которые были добавлены через этот самый GUI, так как все поля на страницах в админке сохранились и остаются рабочими, пропал только раздел с настройками полей. После подключения ACF через PHP я могу их изменять и кажется даже удалять ненужные. Правильно ли я понимаю, что приоритет идет за ACF через PHP ? И возможны ли конфликты между ACF, подключенным через админку и ACF через PHP ?

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал вам назвать в РНР поля именно так, как они названы в GUI тогда конфликтов не будет и все останется рабочим.

Comment: Также, хочу отметить, если кому то пригодится, что в настройках ACF можно сгенерировать PHP код всех полей, которые были созданы в админке и соответственно они будут названы также и все остальное совпадать, как я и сделал, остается лишь добавить его на сайт по инструкции выше

Comment: @mars да, всё именно так, спасибо за комментарий